# Error {"message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"} using kong ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

Getting error msg when I trying to access with public IP:

```
"{"message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"}"
```

Looks like Kong is unable to the upstream services.

I am using voting app

**ingress.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: telehealth-ingress
  namespace: kong
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: voting-service
          servicePort: 80
```

**service.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: voting-service
  labels:
    name: voting-service
    app: voting-app
spec:
  ports:
    - targetPort: 80
      port: 80
  selector:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: voting-app
```

**deployment.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: voting-app-pod
  labels:
    name: voting-app-pod
    app: voting-app
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: voting-app-pod
        app: voting-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: voting-app
          image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_vote
          ports:
           - containerPort: 80
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: voting-app
```

Answer (score 12):

There could be one of many things wrong here. But essentially your ingress cannot get to your backend.

If your backend up and running?

- Check backend pods are "Running"

  ```
  kubectl get pods
  ```
- Check backend deployment has all replicas up

  ```
  kubectl get deploy
  ```
- Connect to the app pod and run a localhost:80 request

  ```
  kubectl exec -it <pod-name> sh
  # curl http://localhost
  ```
- Connect to the ingress pod and see if you can reach the service from there

  ```
  kubectl exec -it <ingress-pod-name> sh
  # dig voting-service  (can you DNS resolve it)
  # telnet voting-sevice 80
  # curl http://voting-service
  ```

[This issue](https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/3518) might shed some insights as to why you can't reach the backend service. What http error code are you seeing?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is resolved after deploying services and deployments in kong namespace instead of default namespace. Now I can access the application with Kong ingress public IP.

Looks like kong ingress is not able to resolve DNS with headless DNS. We need mention FQDN in ingress yaml

Answer (score -1):

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: telehealth-ingress
  namespace: kong
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          name: voting-service
          Port: 
            number: 80
```

Try this i thing it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).